# How to Add Value to a Service Desk Using Data Science?

Tags: career

I work at a Service Desk for a healthcare system, and I am aspiring to be a Data Scientist. What are possible ways I can add value to this department using Data Science? We use ServiceNow for our ticketing System and it's great for analyzing metrics e.g. Call length, Call type, SLA's, etc. I believe though using Python, Statistics, R, and Jupyter Notebooks, more value can be added using Data Science. What projects can you come up with to present to upper management to inspire the use of Data Science, as well? Thank you in advance!

I'm working on an ongoing project of a dataset download via ServiceNow of over 800,000 calls. Using Python I've done some analysis on which agents take the most calls, how long they spend on call, etc. Still a work in progress. I'm hoping for them to accept the use of data Science, and possibly appoint me lead in these projects.